# onChange for Office-fabric-react Textfield doesn't get called

Tags: javascript, typescript

`onChange` for my component is not firing:

```
<TextField 
label = "City"
required = {true}
placeholder = "Location"
value = {this.props.location && this.props.location.Title ?  this.props.location.Title : ""}
onChange = {this._onChangeTitle.bind(this)}
onChanged = {(newValue: string) => {
    console.log("onChanged | newValue: ", newValue);
}}

private _onChangeTitle(event: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>, newValue: string): void {
    console.log("AddRemoveComponent | _onChangeTitle | newValue: ", newValue);

    this._location.Title = newValue;

    console.log("AddRemoveComponent | _onChangeTitle | this._location.Title: ", this._location.Title);
}
```

The `onChanged` will log the new value, but `_onChangeTitle` is never called.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the `@microsoft/sharepoint` scaffolding using older versions of `Typescript` (@2.4.2) it requires us to use an older version of  `office-ui-fabric-react` (@5.127.0) which hasn't implemented `onChange` function yet.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of [`office-ui-fabric-react`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/office-ui-fabric-react) `TextField.change` event should be triggered as expected, [here is a demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/9o13rmn61y) for your reference.

Avoid arrow functions and bind in `render` method (see [here](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md) for a more details) since it might affect the performance, instead one option would be to manually bind the methods in the constructor:

```
 export class TextFieldBasicExample extends React.Component<any, any> {
  private location: {Title:string};

  constructor(props: {}) {
    super(props);
    this.location = {Title:""};
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.onChanged = this.onChanged.bind(this);
  }

  public render(): JSX.Element {
    return (
      <div>
        <TextField
          onChange = {this.onChange}
          onChanged={this.onChanged} />
      </div>
    );
  }

  private onChange(event: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>, newValue: string): void {
    this.location.Title = newValue;
  }

  private onChanged(newValue: string): void {
        this.location.Title = newValue;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'm still learning best practices. I'll look into making those change!